Complicated situation with Schengen & UK Spouse Visa
Can u advise me about a situation? I applied for ITALY visit visa from the UK, I submitted the passport in VAC, LONDON for Italy visit visa. But I am in a weird situation. My visa in the UK is still valid for 10 months. My visa is Spouse/dependent. The problem is I got divorced and I mentioned my marital status as "Divorced" in the Italy/Schengen Visa Application Form. Now that may create confusion. The problem is though I got divorced, my spouse didnt notify the Home Office because she didnt want me to leave anyway and we are currently in the state of reconciliation/remarriage asap. Thats why my UK visa is still valid. I submitted all the necessary documents that qualify me for the Schengen Visa, except for this twist in the story. Yes, if I'd lied to the Italy Embassy, meaning mentioning "married" as Marital status, I may have got away with it easily (which was kinda my mistake!!). Now I am confused, if this mistake/honesty will make suffer for both Schengen and UK visa or not! I mean, the Italy embassy may raise the question how I m still on Spouse visa, if I m divorced, secondly, they may notify home office as well. I m really confused. But I gave them the share code/BRP which cleary says the visa is valid (for 10 months more).
Under this circumstance, what do u think may happen to my fate?
They may overlook the fact that I m divorced, bcoz my UK visa is valid and I m eligible for the Schengen visit visa (which I am)
They may call me and ask for clarification, what should I tell them? Shud, I lie about it being a typing mistake (marital status)?
Is it likely that they notify Home Office of this discrepancy?

What makes you think that the UK visa is still valid? You're no longer married, hence no longer the dependent.

bcoz if u verify, its still valid online, and home office hasnt done anything as of yet. They dont know. we are currently in the state of reconciliation/remarriage asap

The HO hasn’t done anything yet because it doesn’t know. You both have a legal obligation to inform the Home Office of the change in your circumstances. You are breaking UK immigration rules, no matter how you try to dress it up. Remarrying your former spouse won’t be enough to fix that

Failing to notify the Home Office may lead to visa curtailment without warning, which could result in overstaying and potential legal consequences. The HO may consider it an attempt to deceive them, which could affect future visa applications. If you try to remarry your former spouse, your irregular immigration status will come to light.

What is your current right-now marriage status? Have you divorced? Is your divorce final? Your statement "...we are currently in the state of reconciliation/remarriage asap" doesn't make sense, because "Planning to remarry" is not a marriage status. If you were married, and then you divorced, and now you plan to remarry but have not yet done so, then you are still divorced.

@DavidRecallsMonica its final divorce (decree absolute), actually we both didnt know that notifying HO is a MUST, we had no idea, my wife did it impulsively and repented later. Applying for Schengen was a further mistake :( yup legally, I m still divorced.

@Traveller, actually, we both didn't know that notifying HO is mandatory. Even she didn't do this because she didn't want me to leave. As you said, if I try to remarry my former spouse, my irregular immigration status will come to light. Can you tell me how that is? Does the process of marriage here come to HO's notice somehow?

@Tanvir It will come to light because you have to give notice to marry. If you try to give notice with your current visa, the immigration authorities at the Home Office will be told. See inform the HO about a change in circumstances

@Traveller ohh u mean if I remarry that needs to be notified as well, hence causing further problems. What do u think they may do in this case, can they give me 2 months to leave, within which I can remarry and reapply as dependent? Or if they revoke immidieatly, that will be a huge problem :( for me

Your spouse divorced you, but didn’t want you to leave? I believe you need a good immigration lawyer.

@Tanvir They can curtail your visa with immediate effect. The longer you delay telling them, the more likely severe consequences become. IANAL but IMHO you can forget any thoughts of remarrying. You will either have to apply for leave to remain under a different visa route (if you are eligible for one), or leave the UK and reapply as a dependent from outside the UK under the new rules introduced in 2024.
